# Backbone - Syncing simultaneously with Server and LocalStorage

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage, backbone-local-storage

Here is a problem that I am working on:

There is a view and it has a collection. I want to update the UI when the user interaction results in a model being added to the collection. The UI update should be instantaneous. If the web app is open in multiple browser tabs or windows then the view should get updated in all the tabs.

Possible Solution: Use localStorage for caching the data in the browser. Sync with the local server immediately and perform remote sync in the background. Bind UI updates with updates to the localStorage. There are plugins like [Backbone.LocalStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) and [Backbone.DualStorage](https://github.com/nilbus/Backbone.dualStorage). I went through their source code and these plugins do not take care of conflict resolution with server updates i.e. before syncing the data with the localStorage they donot check if the data was synced with the remote server.

Can anyone help me with this? Links to github repos, stackoverflow discussions are welcome.